# The type or namespace name 'myCollection' could not be found

Tags: c#, arguments

Can't seem to solve this error, at the collection part. Is anyone able to help? It says myCollection could not be found but I have declared static on it!
I'm trying to place values into a charting software (sparrowchart) for its value to be updated every second.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections;

namespace Project
{
public partial class temp : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    double Min = 50;
    double Max = 0;
    double[] AvgTemp = new double[101];

    public temp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Pivot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            DispatcherTimer time = new DispatcherTimer();
            time.Tick += time_Tick;
            time.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            time.Start();
        }
    }

    int a = 0,t=0;
    void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer time = new DispatcherTimer();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        double TempRandom = rnd.Next(100, 500); //generate random number
        double TempRandom2 = TempRandom / 10;


        CurrentTemp.Text = TempRandom2.ToString("0.0");
        ViewModel.myCollection.Add(new Model(t++, TempRandom2));
        var myCollection = new myCollection();
            if(myCollection[t] == 10)
            {
                myCollection.RemoveAt(t);
                t--;
            }


        if (TempRandom2 > Max)
        {
            Max = TempRandom2; //Highest Temp = Current Temp

            HighestTemp.Text = Max.ToString("0.0");
        }

        if (TempRandom2 < Min)
        {
            Min = TempRandom2;
            LowestTemp.Text = Min.ToString("0.0"); //Lowest Temp = Current Temp
        }

        AvgTemp[a++ % 100] = TempRandom2;
        if (a > 100)
            AverageTemp.Text = AvgTemp.Average().ToString("0.0");
        else
            AverageTemp.Text = (AvgTemp.Sum() / a).ToString("0.0");
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public Model(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

// Create a ViewModel
public class ViewModel
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Model> myCollection { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    }

}
    }
```

Comment: `new Random()` can give you the same numbers every time if you recreate them within a small time-frame. You should provide a seed value and only create the `Random` object once and then reuse it...

Comment: Why are you creating a new, *empty* collection, removing an element from that *empty* collection, overwriting that collection with a different type of empty collection with a different type of element, and then discarding it altogether?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to C# programming.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are removing specific index, then use `RemoveAt()`:

```
Collection.RemoveAt(t);
```

[Remove(T item)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires `T` item while [RemoveAt(int index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes index.

Comment: Although now he's going to find out what happens when he indexes into an empty list...

Comment: Wow, it removed some errors that I have! Now what's left is the "var Collection = new List<Collection>();" thats giving me the error only

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: what is the type of Collection>?

Comment: Not too sure of it, I've just started to learn C# a week ago on my own. I've edited the code a bit as suggested with the RemoveAt.